# Spread D3.js legend on two columns

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

Hi I have a pretty basic D3.js legend

```
    svg.append('g')
        .classed('legend-color', true)
        .attr('text-anchor', 'start')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(20,30)')
        .style('font-size', '11px')
        .style('fill', 'rgb(0,0,0)')
        .call(legendOrdinal);
```

I would like to spread it in two columns half and half because otherwise the legend cells at the bottom are interfering with my nodes.

So basically it would go from

```
Category A
Category B
Category C
Category D
Category E
Category F
Category G
Category H
```

to

```
    Category A     Category E
    Category B     Category F
    Category C     Category G
    Category D     Category H
```

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: I am using 4.7.4

Comment: I added an answer. Please check :)

Comment: any update....?

Answer (score 3):

With a one column legend you can position each entry easily enough with something like:

```
.attr("transform", function(d,i) {  "translate(10," + (i * 20) +")" });
```

To position multiple columns (and the rows at the same time) we need to adjust the x value of the transform and adjust the y value based on column. The most straightforward way of doing this might be to use the following for x and y:

```
x = Math.floor(i/c) * w + tx
y = i % c * h + ty
```

Where `c` is the number of columns, `w` is the width of each legend entry, `tx` is a base amount all legend entries are translated horizontally, `h` is the height of a legend entry and `ty` is a base amount all legend entries are translated vertically.

You could achieve the above with a function such as:

```
function position(d,i) {
  var c = 2;   // number of columns
  var h = 20;  // legend entry height
  var w = 150; // legend entry width (so we can position the next column) 
  var tx = 10; // tx/ty are essentially margin values
  var ty = 10;
  var x = i % c * w + tx;
  var y = Math.floor(i / c) * h + ty;
  return "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")";
}
```

```js
var entries = "ABCDEFGHIJ".split("");
var color = d3.schemeCategory10;

var n = Math.round(entries.length/2);
var w = 100;
var h = 20;

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 400)
  .attr("height",200);
  
var legend = svg.selectAll("g")
  .data(entries)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", position)
  
legend.append("text")
  .attr("x", 18)
  .attr("y", 12)
  .text(function(d) { return "Category " + d; });

legend.append("rect")
  .attr("width",10)
  .attr("height",10)
  .attr("fill",function(d,i) { return color[i]; })
  
  
function position(d,i) {
  var c = 2;   // number of columns
  var h = 20;  // height of each entry
  var w = 150; // width of each entry (so you can position the next column)
  var tx = 10; // tx/ty are essentially margin values
  var ty = 10;
  var x = i % c * w + tx;
  var y = Math.floor(i / c) * h + ty;
  return "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Or, you could shorten that by condensing it:

```js
var entries = "ABCDEFGHIJ".split("");
var color = d3.schemeCategory10;

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 400)
  .attr("height",200);
  
var legend = svg.selectAll("g")
  .data(entries)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", function(d,i) {
    return "translate(" + (i % 2 * 150 + 10) + "," + (Math.floor(i / 2) * 20 + 10) + ")";
  })
  
legend.append("text")
  .attr("x", 18)
  .attr("y", 12)
  .text(function(d) { return "Category " + d; });

legend.append("rect")
  .attr("width",10)
  .attr("height",10)
  .attr("fill",function(d,i) { return color[i]; })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

---

*If you want the entries in each column to be sequential, rather than the entries of each row, we could modify this a bit to specify a number of rows (determined by how many columns you want and how many legend items you have: `Math.ceil(numberEntries/numberColumns)`. This might look like:*

```js
var entries = "ABCDEFGHIJ".split("");
var color = d3.schemeCategory10;

var n = Math.round(entries.length/2);
var w = 100;
var h = 20;

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 400)
  .attr("height",200);
  
var legend = svg.selectAll("g")
  .data(entries)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", position)
  
legend.append("text")
  .attr("x", 18)
  .attr("y", 12)
  .text(function(d) { return "Category " + d; });

legend.append("rect")
  .attr("width",10)
  .attr("height",10)
  .attr("fill",function(d,i) { return color[i]; })
  
  
function position(d,i) {
  var c = 3
  var r = Math.ceil(entries.length / c);
  var h = 20;  // height of each entry
  var w = 100; // width of each entry (so you can position the next column)
  var tx = 10; // tx/ty are essentially margin values
  var ty = 10;
  var x = Math.floor(i / r) * w + tx;
  var y = i % r * h + ty;
  return "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

*This method could lead to the last column having only one entry, while the first method above might have one row with only one entry. Depending on circumstance, one or the other may be more preferable*

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function for `transform` attribute and change the layout based on your logic.

Here's a simple example:

Instead of `.attr('transform', 'translate(20,30)')`, give something like this:

```
.attr('transform', function(data, index){

      var sections = Math.round((Object.keys(slices).length - 1) / 2);

      if(index < sections)
        return 'translate(0,0)'; 
      else
        return 'translate(80,-40)'; 
    });
```

This is a very simple logic I wrote just to show you the idea. I count how many elements would be there in one column, then change each of its `translate` property based on it's index.

Here's a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nimeshka/wbejmg30/35/

Check the last code block in the above fiddle to see this.

Hope it helps!!